# Knockout.js input focus after click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to set focus on an input with knockout after the click event is fired but couldn't find a clean way to handle it without coupling with the DOM. Here is the JS code I have:

```
(function() {

    var vm = {
        text: ko.observable(),
        items: ko.observableArray([])
    }

    vm.addItem = function() { 
        vm.items.push(vm.text());
        vm.text(null);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(vm);

}());
```

This is my DOM:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: text" />
<a href="#" data-bind="click: addItem">Send</a>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JsFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/srJUa/1/

What I want it to set focus on the input after the `vm.addItem` is completed. Any idea how this can be done cleanly, for example with a custom knockout binding?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Knockout has a built-in binding for manipulating the focus: [The "hasfocus" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html).

So you just need to create a boolean property on your viewmodel and bind it on your input and set the property to `true` if you want to focus the input.

Or in your case you can binding directly to your `text` property, so when it is does not have any text it should has the focus:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: text, hasfocus: !text()" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BBNH/).

Comment: thanks!:) it has just came to my mind and I solved it the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/srJUa/2/

Answer (score 4):

OK, I have solved the issue by leveraging the hasfocus binding:

```
(function() {

    var vm = {
        text: ko.observable(),
        items: ko.observableArray([]),
        isFocused: ko.observable()
    }

    vm.addItem = function() { 
        vm.items.push(vm.text());
        vm.text(null);
        vm.isFocused(true);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(vm);

}());
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: text, hasfocus: isFocused" />
<a href="#" data-bind="click: addItem">Send</a>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/srJUa/2/

Not sure if this is the best way, though.